# Issue with saving my objects

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a problem with saving my entity, i use `spring` 4 and `hibernate` 4.

```
   @Repository
   public class AuthDao {

   @Autowired 
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Transactional
   public void enregistrer(Auth auth) {
     Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(auth);
  }
```

No entry in my database was added.
But if i want just read it's okey.

```
session.get(Auth.class, 2)
```

my second problem is i want understand why when i put:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

it doesn't work and i got :

```
No Session found for current thread
```

my other files:

```
@Controller
public class testController {


@Autowired 
private AuthDao authDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/cc")
public String printWelcome() {

    authDao.enregistrer(new Auth(7, "test", "test"));
    return "hello";

}
```

}

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    ...
</bean>



<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question:
 the HibernateSession is a first level cache, the data will not saved (in data base) until the session is closed (tipically in the commit transaction), but data are accesible for some queries. [This link explain it very well](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/02/16/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-one-the-session-cache/).

The second question:
 You are asking for the current HibernateSession, but is possible that is not accessible because it has not been created or opened.

In my personal opinion, this isn't the best way to integrate Spring and Hibernate, I think you should use the HiberanteTemplate, maybe this [tutorial](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-hibernate-xml-config-code-example.html) would help you.

Comment: But even when i close all my project and i close eclipse no object is saved !! i know with hibernate template is better but i want to know where the problem come from first.

Comment: did you close the HibernateSession (session.close())?? In any way, I´m not sure how hibernate manage AUTO_COMMIT, but you must work with transactional marks . HibernateTemplate give you easy (and safe) ways to use HibernateSesion. An example (only hibernate) `Session sess =      factory.openSession();
   Transaction tx;
   try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }`

Comment: `session.close()` doesn't work. but `session.flush()` works even if i remove all `@Transactional` and `transactionManager` bean, i'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

it's work now i forget to put

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

and i put

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

it seem to work after `tx:annotation-driven` sessionFactory.openSession() doesn't open the right session i think.

but can anyone explain me why ?